# Tax rules for NOT LOGGED IN USER

Tags: tax, magento-2.1.3

I've created tax rules for wholesaler and retail users. 
Being a registered customer this tax rules are working fine.
But being NOT LOGGED IN user no rules are taken.
I would like to distinguish also for "NOT LOGGED IN" user if it's a retailer or wholesaler.
Is there a possibility to do this adaptation?

Answer (score 0):

Unless a user is logged in how can system make out whether a user is retailer or wholesaler.

On checkout you can add an additional section with fields like Reseller ID and ID value.If some one fills this then let your code know that this is a wholesaler guest and according set B2B tax system(  Zero Percent).

If you search for Tax exempt module in Magento 2 you will find our module which handles guest with Tax exemption.